# Does exponential backoff make sense when checking conditions in AJAX apps?

Tags: selenium

There are many tests that wait for certain condition to be satisfied, for instance UI tests wait for message to appear on a page. This is usually implemented by polling: repeating a check x times every n seconds. For instance, `ExplicitWait` in Selenium/WebDriver is implemented like that.

This causes checks to be performed regularly.

However, another strategy could be possible. I have read about [exponential backoff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) that multiplicatively decrease the rate of some process, in order to gradually find an acceptable rate. This makes sense in repeating a request to a server when connection is temporarily broken. It's better to repeat a check after 1 second, than after 2 seconds, 4 seconds, 8 seconds, etc.

Would this strategy be useful in case of AJAX applications to load elements dynamically? In other word, to implement `ExplicitWait` with such exponential backoff?

Comment: I guess it would be possible, if someone decided to spend the effort to develop the patch, but I am not sure if benefit is worth the effort. In most cases, CPU is idle anyway. This would make test slower and CPU idler.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I think you're right, in case of network it is used to avoid network congestion (sending packets when service is down). In case of Selenium I don't see such a benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible and a viable strategy.

Hence the real question is "what is the benefit?" - in your question, what does 'make sense' mean.

I will assume that 'makes sense' means there is a worthwhile benefit from doing this.

I do not see any benefit so I would advise against it (after a few iterations the spacing becomes large) unless there is something going on like the cpu is pegging, the machine is overheating, etc.

Comment: ...and if CPU is close to being maxed out, spending some cash on better, faster server with more RAM is simpler, one-time investment, requires less time, and benefits other areas too.

Answer (score 1):

For standard automation testing I think it's counter-productive as the test is usually frozen and waiting on something before acting.  Adding time between polling would be similar to just adding implicit waits to the test case causing it to run longer.

I always like an explicit wait where possible.  I would still encourage that even if you have interface waiting that you target a specific occurrence and not rely on something like this.  This is a great algorithm for operations, but i don't really see a good use for it in automation testing except to test the algorithm, which would then not be you programming it, but testing against an existing usage of it.

Performance testing on the other hand would likely be a great place to utilize this.  The only caveat is that if it's supposed to load the system in a particular way you would be defeating your test by doing it.  However, if it's not supposed to be a load test on a particular item it could help your test not bottleneck when everything is trying to do the same thing.

Testing in general though is targeting issues and that method is to avoid issues...therefore in general it defeats the purpose for testing.